# Xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATTrackingManager"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm exporting a project from Unity to IOS (Xcode), and when building I'm getting this error in Xcode. What should I do?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATTrackingManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGameAnalytics.a(GADevice.o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a "unity" guy, but from the looks of the error message you do not have a symbol included in your project by that name ... looks like it's trying to find the symbol from a static library named "libGameAnalytics" and looking for the GADevice object file (notice the "dot 'O').  If you are setting up a regular Xcode/iOS project then I'd recommend you use the corresponding "native" Swift/Objective-C Frameworks, static libraries, Cocoapods, or import source files.

Try making that replacement from Xcode's project file, and see if your error goes away ... it's at least a place to begin investigation, and might provide additional insight to the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift/Objective-C and Xcode in general :(, I'm always exporting the unity project and building it for IOS using Xcode. Can you tell more about what source files should I import?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that Xcode is complaining about it can't find the symbol named "_obj_class_$_ATTrckingManager".  I assume this symbol would normally be found in a library called "GameAnalyitcs" within a class called GADevice??  If true, go grab the Swift or Objective-C version of the file from the manufacture, and add that to your Xcode project.  Hopefully, whatever API you'd normally use through Unity is same/similar enough that it will just compile without requiring any tweaking to the calling code.  They might only provide static library, which can be used just fine also from Xcode.

Comment: Exactly, usually this error should not happen, because everything is implemented via Unity, it's the first time having this issue, so weird

Comment: Apparently, not everything.  Unity might have been the call-site, but I assume it was using the same analytics package as what Xcode it looking for, no?  I admit that I might be totally talking out my ass, but if I didn't know better I'd say "add this library to Xcode (the Xcode way), and check the call-sites (might be a slight tweak required)".  You should be good to go.